# Application validation did not complete

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment

This is not a unique question, but my googling around hasn't been able to solve this problem for me. I've tried to publich a WPF app with ClickOnce to a USB drive, but when I run the setup.exe I get the following error message: "Application validation did not succeed. Unable to continue."

When I go to the generated textfile to see what's what, I find this error summary:

```
ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of E:\deploy\TileServer\Http Tile Server.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly DBIndexer_hidden.exe.
```

I found someone who mentioned you could go to Properties -> application -> resources and set the Manifest tab to "Create application without a manifest" but the problem still occurs.

Any hints to how I can get rid of this error or what might be causing it?